# Having trouble making a OAuth 1.0a signed request to the Tumblr API using HelloJS

Tags: api, oauth, tumblr, hello.js

I'm trying to interface with the Tumblr API to pull a list of followers.  I'm brand new the whole OAuth thing, so I was trying to model my calls off the demos at https://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/tumblr.html . Unfortunately, the example they give only requires the API key for identification (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) where as getting the followers needs a signed OAuth request (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#followers).

The call I'm using is:

```
function getFollowers(blog){
  hello('tumblr').api('blog/'+blog+'/followers/').then(function(r){
    console.log("r", r);
    //Bellow here not really relevant
    var a = r.data.map(function(item){
      return "<h2>"+item.title+"</h2>"+item.body_abstract;
    });
    document.getElementById('blogs').innerHTML = a.join('');
  });
}
```

This generates the request url from the proxy:

```
https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy?path=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.tumblr.com%2Fv2%2Fblog%2Fnmlapp.tumblr.com%2Ffollowers%2F%3Fapi_key%3DREDACTED08u%26callback%3D_hellojs_9kvqxi31&access_token=&then=redirect&method=get&suppress_response_codes=truee
```

and Tumblr's API returns

```
_hellojs_9kvqxi31({"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]});
```

I can see that the login call has all of the OAuth info in the Query String Parameters field, and the one I'm trying to make does not, but I'm not sure what the right way to include that through helloJS is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, the function had to be wrapped in the login method.  This was shown in the other example, but the way that it called parameters from the api object had me confused.

```
function doTheThing(network){
hello( network ).login({force:false}).then( function(r){

  hello('tumblr').api('followers').then(function(r){
    console.log("r", r);

    var a = r.data.map(function(item){
      return "<h2>"+item.title+"</h2>"+item.body_abstract;
    });
    document.getElementById('blogs').innerHTML = a.join('');
  });
  });
  }

//...
tumblr:{
 get: {
   //...
   //This next part needs to be generated dynamically, but you get the idea
    'followers': 'blog/BLOGNAME.tumblr.com/followers',
      }

      callback(p.path);
    }
  },

  post: {
    //...
    'followers': function(p, callback) {
      p.path = 'followers';
      query(p, callback);
    }
  },
```